# Convert table wp_users(Wordpress) to table users(Java) - Security login

Tags: java, php, wordpress, spring-security, jhipster

I have converting data from Wordpress to java spring boot(jhipster). The problem is table wp_users in database. Wordpress used special algorithm to encrypt user password. I see class wp-includes/class-phpass.php in wordpress make this. That i found have no other way decryption user password to read.
 My ideas follow this:

1.Export all users in wp_users to excel(with user password have decypt)(Not yet)

### 2.insert data with java encrypt.

Please help me! thank you !

Comment: You can not decrypt the Wordpress passwords.
The solution here is to copy the passwords as it is, and change your new applications login method to mimic Wordpress's login method.

Comment: Any system that encrypts their passwords in a way that is possible to decrypt, is not a secure system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problems had solved. Have no way to decrypt password in wordpress so i used format encrypt the same in java.Thank all !